# Logarithmically divergent integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

I am not able to find the following definition: 
When an integral is said to be logarithmically divergent integral?
Can someone help me to get it?

Comment: Try the google search ["integral" + "logarithmically divergent" + "definition"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22integral%22+%22logarithmically+divergent%22+%22definition%22). For example, a definition (that seems a bit imprecise to me, by the way) can be found in [these notes](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~kayeats/teaching/co739_w18/lec15_summary.pdf), which was the 9th result for me.

Answer (score 2):

For an integral to be logarithmic divergent, conditions are met for integrals of the type
$$
I(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{p}\mathrm d p
$$
or potenitally of the form $$I(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{p}f(p)\mathrm d p$$ where $f(p)$ approaches a finite limit when $p \to\infty$). In both of these cases, the integral diverges to infinity when $x\to\infty$, and is observede to do so slowly.

(I deliberately chose the free parameter $p$ here as I am assuming you are a student of some kind of QFT as this notion of divergence appears in Perturbative QFT?)